# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException :Unable to find element with id

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

webdriver code is not working in C# with

```
Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink")).Click();
```

and I have tried with

```
Driver.FindElement(By.id
```

but it is not working and I am getting below error in visualstudio
error message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with id == portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink
```

Error stack trace:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute,  Dictionary`2 parameters)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
SeleniumTests.ReviewCase.TheReviewCaseTest() in C:\Automation\CSharp\SpecExperiment\SpecExperiment\UnitTest2.cs: line 46
```

Comment: Post your element HTML code please.

Comment: <A id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink onclick="oc.ajax.jsf.doCallback('portletComponentWorkList','portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:showFiltersLink');return false;" href="#">Show filters</A>

Comment: your ways to locate element seem legit... What are you doing just before clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Show filters")).Click();`

Comment: I have tried but it is showing error message as below "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with link text == Show filters"

Comment: Do you have implicit wait in your code something like Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); ? One more thing to check -see if your link is inside  a frame, in that case you need to switch to that frame before clicking it.